# AMD ATi Radeon HD 6870 drivers not working

Tags: drivers, ati, games, opengl

Need some help with this. I've searched for a few hours and found no answer that worked for me.

When I try to install my drivers I get

> One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system.
>   Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver. Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools. Forcing install will disable AMD hardware accelleration and may make your system unstable.
>   Not recommended.
>   See /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.

So I checked that log and it gave me

> Supported adapter detected.
>   Check if system has the tools required for installation.
>   fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.8.0-6-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
>   One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
>   Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
>   Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.

Comment: Did you install the driver from AMDs site or from "Additional drivers" in Ubuntu? Also: which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Using the proprietary ones from the AMD site, running Ubuntu 13.04. Thanks for the quick response. :)

Comment: that's not good. You should install drivers through ubuntu packages. Don't worry we'll fix it.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Wait I think I've found it. Thanks for telling me and your quick responce! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok first we have to remove all your previous installations.

In the terminal run:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

now go to dash, open software sources, go to additional drivers tab. You should see the catalyst 13.2 beta 3 driver, activate it.

when you're done, in the term run:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
```

reboot.

Comment: I have tried the steps and the additional drivers tab is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver from here : http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-3LINBetaDriver.aspx

To install refer to the second part of the answer on `/questions/18747/`.

I don't use fglrx drivers because they're not the same ones issued by AMD, and given this is all proprietary, then there's no point not going to the source instead of Xorg.